# Correct way to instantiate a generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, instantiation

Weak in generic, please go easy! 
I have some base and derived classes structured as below via generics

```
public abstract class ProcessingNode<T extends APICommand> extends Node {
}

public class CustomerProcessingNode extends ProcessingNode<CHDAPICommand> {
}

public class MerchantProcessingNode extends ProcessingNode<MHDAPICommand> {
}

public class APICommand {
}

public class CHDAPICommand extends APICommand {
}

public class MHDAPICommand extends APICommand {
}
```

Now, during server start i would want to pick the right `ProcessingNode` and cache it as below:

```
private void cacheProcessingNodeManager() throws ListenerException {
    // throws Unexpected Bound error
    ProcessingNode<T extends APICommand> processingNodeManager = null;      
    if (condition1 is true){
        // throws "required ProcessingNode<T> but found CustomerProcessingNode"
        processingNodeManager = new CustomerProcessingNode();               
    }
    else if (condition2 is true){
        // throws "required ProcessingNode<T> but found MerchantProcessingNode"
        processingNodeManager = new MerchantProcessingNode();               
    } else {
        // some exception
    }
    // cache processingNodeManager
}
```

but i get 2 error as highlighted in comments above.

What would be the right way to create specific objects of `ProcessingNode`?

Comment: What is `T` in the context of your method `cacheProcessingNodeManager`? You can't dynamically decide inside the method that `T` has to be `CHDAPICommand` or `MHDAPICommand`; it has to be known at compile time.

Comment: The declaration `ProcessingNode<T extends APICommand> processingNodeManager = null;` is incorrect. Did you mean `ProcessingNode<? extends APICommand> processingNodeManager = null;`?

Comment: @ernest_k yup...thats solves!!

Comment: @Jesper aahhh....super stupid noob, `<?>` is what i should be doing the bound with instead of `<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't decide `T` has to be `CHDAPICommand` or `MHDAPICommand` inside the method `cacheProcessingNodeManager()`. You can only decide `T` when declaring class and method.

You can create specific objects of `ProcessingNode` in two ways.

1. use Wild Card Generic

```
    public void cacheProcessingNodeManager() throws Exception {
        ProcessingNode<? extends APICommand> processingNodeManager = null;

        if (condition1 is true){
            processingNodeManager = new CustomerProcessingNode();
        } else if (condition2 is true){
            processingNodeManager = new MerchantProcessingNode();
        } else {
            // some exception
        }
    }
```

2. declaring Generic with method and use upcasting

```
    public <T extends APICommand>void cacheProcessingNodeManager() throws Exception {
        ProcessingNode<T> processingNodeManager = null;

        if (condition1 is true){
            processingNodeManager = (ProcessingNode<T>) new CustomerProcessingNode();
        } else if (condition2 is true) {
            processingNodeManager = (ProcessingNode<T>) new MerchantProcessingNode();
        } else {
            // some exception
        }
    }
```